# What does it mean to say that a sequence $x_n, n=1,2,3,\ldots$ of real numbers is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

And also, following on from the question in the title.

Suppose $x_n$, $n = 1,2,3,\ldots$ is a sequence of positive real numbers that does not tend to infinity. Explain why it must be possible to construct a sub-sequence of $x_n$ that is bounded.

Please bear in mind I'm new to analysis, so adjust your answers accordingly.

Thanks

The full question can be found here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fBUv.jpg

Comment: You haave surely been given a definition of what it means for a sequence to be bounded —otherwise, the second question would be simply impossible for you to even understand. It will probably be best if you transcribed the definition of bounded sequence that you have, and that we help you understand it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly what you wanted to ask. If a sequence of real numbers does not tend to infinity there exists a real number $M$ such that $M \geq x_n$ $\forall n$.

Comment: There is a part a) to the question which is very long to type out, I'll post a link to the question here - http://imgur.com/Gz4cCKb

Comment: I am afraid part c) of the question only makes sense if you drop the assumption that the numbers must be positive.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $-1,-2,-3,\ldots$ has no bounded subsequence, but it does not tend to $+\infty$.

The proposition asserted makes sense if instead of $\pm\infty$ one has just one $\infty$, which is approached by sequences like $+1,-2,+3,-4,\ldots$, and that certainly makes sense in some contexts.

If one does that, then "tends to $\infty$" means for every $M>0$, not matter how big, the sequence eventually gets out of the interval $[-M,M]$ and subsequently stays out of that interval.

"Does not tend to infinity" therefore means that there is some number $M>0$ such that no matter how far you go down the sequence, you will at some time at or after that point return to the interval $[-M,M]$.

That gives you a bounded subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_{n}$ doesn't tend to $ + \infty$ , by definition of convergence to $+ \infty$ there exists $ M > 0$ such that for every $k \in \mathbb{N} \ \ \exists n_{k} > k $ with $$x_{n_{k}} \in [0,M]$$ So you have a bounded subsequence.

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence to be bounded?

Answer (score 0):

A sequence of numbers $x_n$ is *bounded* if there is some number $N$ such that $|x_n|<N$ for all $n$ (equivalently, $-N\leq x_n\leq N$). In other words, a sequence is bounded if we can find a number that is bigger than all of its terms and a number that is smaller than all of its terms. For example, the sequence $x_n=\sin(n)$ is bounded because $-1\leq\sin(n)\leq 1$ for any $n$, but the sequence $x_n=n^2$ is not bounded (why?).

To show that a sequence that does not tend to infinity has a bounded subsequence, try proving the contrapositive: if every subsequence is unbounded then the sequence tends to infinity.